# Export a Matrix in txt file

Tags: python, matrix, export

I'm trying to Export a Matrix to a .txt file with the following Code

```
with open('outfile.txt','wb') as f:
   for line in M:
        np.savetxt(f, line, fmt='%.4f')
```

The Problem is that the file that I obtain, sparates the numbers in different rows, ant it looks something like:

```
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.
0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -0.2
998 -0.2966 -0.2945 …
```

How could I tell python to use each row of the Matrix M as a new complete row oth the .txt file?

Thank you in advance

Comment: it's not recommended to save numpy arrays as txt files. You can use [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) to save it as .npy binary file

Comment: Thanks but I need it specifically in .txt format

Answer (score 0):

If this is a 2-D matrix. The easiest thing to do is make sure it is in numpy format and use numpy.savetxt().

Link to documentation below. 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('outfile.txt','wb') as f:
   for line in M:
        np.savetxt(f, line + '\n', fmt='%.4f')
```

'\n' should move caret to new line

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's built-in file object like such:

```
M = np.random.randn(10,10)
f = open("outfile.txt","w")
for row in M:
    for el in row:
        f.write("%.4f" %el + ' ')
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

note that this print a new line everytime a row has been fully printed.